# how to initialize the list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have created a list like this,

```
public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = 
            new List<string> { ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG" };
```

It was accepted in all .NET Framework versions except 2.0 (2005).

In 2.0, it was only accepted using `()`.

```
public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = 
            new List<string>() { ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG" };
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Thats just a short-term when using collection initializer the default constructor will be called. So no difference. Both will compile into same thing.

Comment: yes right but when i trying to run in 2005(2.0 frame word) it shown below error  Form1.cs(1426,80): error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type

Comment: Quote from link "Just to be clear, if your compiler is of 3 or greater, you can target 2.0, to get this to work (because it's compiled down to the code that Andrew shows, below). But if your compiler is 2, then you can't."

Comment: Thats. Net 2 framework not frame _word_. However its not about framework. old version compilers does not support it. i.e C#2