# Difference in initialize the list

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2005

i have initialize the list in VS 2013 like this

```
public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = new List<string>() { ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG" };
```

it's working fine in vs 2013 but vs 2005 it throw error so i have used like this below,

```
public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = new List<string>(new String[] { ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG" });
```

it's working fine in both vs 2013 and vs 2005.. why first code is not work in vs 2005 and what's the difference b/w both code

Comment: you already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932432/how-to-initialize-the-list-in-c-sharp

Comment: Because vs2005 supports .Net Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that first way of initializing is using [collection initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062(v=vs.90).aspx), which were introduced only in .NET 3.0, that is in Visual Studio 2008. Therefore they don't compile in Visual Studio 2005.

Second way is using [the constructor of `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx), which was available since introduction of generics in .NET 2.0, so it is available in Visual Studio 2005 as well.